# how to make audio meter level with avaudiorecorder

Tags: iphone

I am trying to create a audio meter level while I am recording the user voice using avaudiorecorder. Can someone help me in that regard?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Actually, the code is pretty straightforward since AVAudioPlayer and AVAudioRecorder have built in methods to get you on your way. My approach was this:

- make a repeating call to `-updateMeters` and the `averagePowerForChannel:` & `peakPowerForChannel:` methods and call a delegate method to notify the controlling object

Example:

```
NSOperationQueue *queue=[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
NSInvocationOperation *operation=[[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(updateMeter) object:nil];
[queue addOperation: operation];
```

and

```
-(void)updateMeter
{
  do {
      //don't forget:
      [recorder updateMeters];
       self.averagePower   = [recorder averagePowerForChannel:0];
       self.peakPower      = [recorder peakPowerForChannel:0];

       // we don't want to surprise a ViewController with a method call
       // not in the main thread
      [self.delegate performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector(meterLevelsDidUpdate:) withObject:self waitUntilDone:NO];
      [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:.05]; // 20 FPS
     }while(someCondition);
}
```

If your View Controller implements the `meterLevelsDidUpdate:` method, you can use this method to update your Level Meter.

- create a UIView subclass with a subview that changes its height according to the average or peak value(s). Adjust to taste.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. Newbies like me need to remember to set meteringEnabled = YES.

Comment: Do you know what is the time range for it? Does it pick peak value since last `updateMeters`, in your case 0.05 sec before? What about when I want to pick max from the full time range? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30866132/time-range-for-peakpowerforchannel-or-averagepowerforchannel

Answer (score 7):

Easy, you can use NSTimer for that:

```
- (void)startAudioMetering {
    self.meterTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(updateAudioMeter)userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)stopAudioMetering {
    [self.meterTimer invalidate];
}

- (void)updateAudioMeter { //called by timer
    // audioRecorder being your instance of AVAudioRecorder
    [self.audioRecorder updateMeters];
    self.dBLevel = [self.audioRecorder averagePowerForChannel:0];
}
```

**WARNING**: While creating your AVAudioRecorder instance, you have to call meteringEnabled AFTER you call prepareToRecord or record, otherwise it won't updateMeters:

```
[self.audioRecorder prepareToRecord];
self.audioRecorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift** code based on Tom's answer:

```
 NSOperationQueue().addOperationWithBlock({[weak self] in
        repeat {
            self?.audioRecorder.updateMeters()
            self?.averagePower = self?.audioRecorder.averagePowerForChannel(0)
            self?.peakPower = self?.audioRecorder.peakPowerForChannel(0)

            self?.performSelectorOnMainThread(#selector(DictaphoneViewController.updateMeter), withObject: self, waitUntilDone: false)
            NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(0.05)//20 FPS
        }
            while (someCondition)
        })
```

Do the meter UI stuff inside `func updateMeter(){//UI stuff here}`

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty simple,
The values you get in the buffer are positive and negative (this is how the waves work) so if you do the average of that values it will give you a near 0 value.

So what you have to do is just put all values positive (with the Math.abs() function) and then do the avarage, it will return you the sound level.

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: thanks for replying Jordi, But how will I check it continuously? I could not find any delegate method for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use ReactiveCocoa and make use of [`interval:onScheduler:`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/ReactiveCocoa/2.3.1/Classes/RACSignal.html#//api/name/interval:onScheduler:):

> Returns a signal that sends the current date/time every interval on scheduler.

Using a single audio channel:

```
  @weakify(self)
  RACDisposable *metersDisposable = [[RACSignal // make sure you dispose it eventually
      interval:0.1
      onScheduler:[RACScheduler scheduler]]
      subscribeNext:^(NSDate *) {
        @strongify(self)
        [recorder updateMeters];
        auto averagePower = [recorder averagePowerForChannel:0];
        auto peakPower = [recorder peakPowerForChannel:0];
        // Inform the delegate or make other use of averagePower and peakPower
      }];
```

Answer (score -5):

I found the answer in following link.

[AVMeter for AVPlayer](http://exploitation-forestiere-jammes.com/iphone/avmeter_colon_build_a_vu_meter.html)

Though it requires lot of customizations but I feel I will be able to do it.

Comment: The link no longer works. Do you have the information somewhere else?

Comment: http://lovingod.host.sk/iphone/developers/avmeter_colon_build_a_vu_meter.html seems to be it.